# CSS change d property of <path>

Tags: css, svg

I have a generated svg path code, I want to override it with CSS file to change the svg shape.
I could override all the properties except 'd':

Here is the generated code (I can't change it directly):

```
<div id="map_outer" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; z-index: 1;">
<svg height="35" version="1.1" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
</defs>
<path fill="#cecece" stroke="#808080" d="M503.7,743.8C694,647.1999999999999,636.6,326.74999999999994,348.1,334.09V205.39L120.00000000000003,400.39L348.1,606.19V474.59000000000003C589,469.09000000000003,578,677.3900000000001,503.70000000000005,743.8900000000001Z" stroke-width="40" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.05,0,0,0.05,-1.9,-5.7)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS to override the d value, I get

> Unknown property name

in the CSS inspector !!! :

[image]

```
#map_outer svg path{
    fill: rgb(255, 204, 0) !important;
    d:"M 850 300 C 850 300 350 300 350 300 L 348.1 205.39 L 120 400.39 L 348.1 606.19 L 350 500 C 850 500 850 500 850 500 z" !important;
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with CSS. CSS was not designed to do this. You will have to use JavaScript, and then the process becomes trivial. If you need to use CSS selectors for this, try jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure any UI supports d as a CSS property? This Chrome bug for it is still in progress: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652822. I think you're beyond even the bleeding edge here.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman any way to do it in JS or JQuery ?

Comment: This unfortunatly doesn't work in FF

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're almost on the right track here, you just need to set the correct value for the property. It's missing **path('..')**:

```
#map_outer svg path {
    d: path('M 850 300 C 850 300 350 300 350 300 L 348.1 205.39 L 120 400.39 L 348.1 606.19 L 350 500 C 850 500 850 500 850 500 z') !important;
}
```

Comment: I did not knew that trick, nice one. I was going for the `<script>document.body.onload=function(){document.getElementById("map_outer").getElementsByTagName("path")[0].setAttribute("d", "M 0 0 L 0 50 L 50 50")};</script>` way.

Comment: That will break once Chrome implement the correct syntax for d https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652822

Comment: And it currently works just in Chrome-based browsers, nowhere else. (But cool remark anyway, @brendonofficial!)

Comment: Did anybody have an issue with this not working on safari?

Comment: Firefox will support path data in styles from version 93. The spec has been changed, so this should be future proof.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `id` to your `<path d="..."></path>` and then the JavaScript code with the new path:

```
<svg>
  <path d="..." id="myPath></path>
</svg>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myPath").setAttribute("d", "M 0 0 L 0 50 L 50 50");
</script>
```

Here's an example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <path d="M 0 0 L 50 0 L 50 50" id="myPath" />
    </svg>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myPath").setAttribute("d", "M 0 0 L 0 50 L 50 50");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not change the code, it is generated by a complicated JS file, The JS file ganarated other staff too. So I can only manage outside this piece of code

Comment: Does the `<path>` has any `id` or way to get it from JS?

Comment: Only the #map_outer div has an id

Comment: Okay, that will do I think. Give me a moment so I can change the code...