# Invalid property name for svg attributes in scss

Tags: css, angular, svg, sass

I am using Angular 6 in my project and scss. I am getting warnings run my project. It is mostly warnings for svg element style. For example:
This is styles for svg `path` element:

```
.marker-target {
  stroke: none;
  fill: $dark-gray;
  d: path('M 10 0 L 3 5 L 10 10 z'); // here is warning 'Invalid property name d'
}
```

Or `<circle />` and styles for it:

```
circle {
  r: 9 // here is warning 'Invalid property name r'
}
```

And so on. How i can fix this?

Comment: Some of these CSS properties are only supported by Chrome. You're on the bleeding edge here.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227012/css-change-d-property-of-path

Comment: My project is mainly focused on Chrome, so it is not the problem. But as you can see `d: path('M 10 0 L 3 5 L 10 10 z');` i already use the same syntax for defining path as in your link. But i still got warnings. Is there any way to get rid of them, except block all warings at all

Comment: These are *experimental* properties. You *want* these warnings since they tell you that they won't work in all browsers. As for how you diable them that will depend on your IDE.