# Rotate actual svg path 90 degrees?

Tags: svg, transform

I have this path that I want to rotate 90 degrees. Not just rotate the whole element, I want to change the actual path to get an up arrow as well as a down arrow. Is there a path transform tool out there or some other easy way to do it?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M8.578 16.359l4.594-4.594-4.594-4.594 1.406-1.406 6 6-6 6z"></path>
</svg>
```

I actually found an svg library that had the exact shapes that I'm looking for (see below). If anyone can tell me how I would have reached that result on my own that would be great. Thanks!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M7.406 7.828l4.594 4.594 4.594-4.594 1.406 1.406-6 6-6-6z"></path>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M7.406 15.422l-1.406-1.406 6-6 6 6-1.406 1.406-4.594-4.594z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: SeaBass, this page will likely help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform.

Comment: @John Thanks John. That also looks like it rotates the element instead of changing the path. My ultimate goal is actually to use the path in css, which is why I tagged it with css, but for my example I just included it in an svg element. I will put it as a css background using `:after` and don't want to rotate anything else, which is why I want to attack the core and change the whole path. Makes sense?

Comment: "If anyone can tell me how I would have reached that result on my own that would be great." The answer to this question is to learn how the SVG path format works by reading [the SVG specifcation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-paths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a `viewBox` attribute to the svg element. I'm using `viewBox="-12 -12 24 24"` which means that the point 0,0 is in the very middle of the svg canvas. Next I'n using [`<polyline>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline) to create the arrow. Since I'm using round numbers I can code the arrow manually.

`points="0,-10 10,0 0,10"` means that y first move to the point `x:0,y:-10`, I draw a line to the point `x:10,y:0` and finally to the point `X:0,y:10`

I've setter the `width` of the svg element `width="100"` but you can change it to what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
polyline{fill:none; stroke:black;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-linecap: round;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <polyline points="0,-10 10,0 0,10" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <polyline points="0,-10 -10,0 0,10" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <polyline points="-10,0 0,-10 10,0" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <polyline points="-10,0 0,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

If you don't like `<polyline>` and you want to use path this is how you would do it:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-linecap: round;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <path d="M0,-10 L10,0 0,10" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <path d="M0,-10 L-10,0 0,10" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <path d="M-10,0 L0,-10 10,0" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" width="100">
  <path d="M-10,0 L0,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS solution for transforming `<path>`.

```css
path{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M8.578 16.359l4.594-4.594-4.594-4.594 1.406-1.406 6 6-6 6z"></path>
</svg>
```

I don't know the browser support for the `transform-box` but this thing actually solved my problem in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap in div and stylize. You can of course use the style immediately for svg but not all browsers support it.

```css
.icon {
 height: 20px;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='icon'>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M8.578 16.359l4.594-4.594-4.594-4.594 1.406-1.406 6 6-6 6z"></path>
 </svg>
</div>
```

You can also use the attribute 'transform'.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path transform='rotate(90 10 10)' d="M8.578 16.359l4.594-4.594-4.594-4.594 1.406-1.406 6 6-6 6z"></path>
</svg>
```

Apparently there are no other simple ways. But you can also [determine the path in css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227462/10429440)

If you insert svg through background (:before or :after) [you will not be able to change at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image). Only via rotate in css.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to rotate the whole element, I want to change the actual path.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I was thinking if there was an online editor where I could paste the path and hit rotate (or edit in other ways) and get a new path. My googling said that there is no background-rotate css element, which when I think about it is weird since you can choose position, size and everything else.

Comment: @SeaBass Looks like you were looking for something [like this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=henoc.svgeditor&ssr=false#overview).

Comment: I didn't find a demo, but it looks good! Checking out. Thanks

Comment: This guy is going to start an edit war so instead I'll state right here: you do not need to pointlessly add another frigin `div` when you can apply the `transform` directly on the `svg` element itself.