# Transform origin not working with hover ScaleX SVG Path

Tags: css, transform, scale

Is it possible to have the left end of `.line` at the same place when hover? I thought `transform-origin` would do the trick.

```css
.line{
transition: .3s;
transform-origin: left;
}

body:hover .line{transform:scaleX(2);}
```

```html
<div>

<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 62 52" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <path class="line" d="m15.665 25.123h20v1h-20z" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution:

animate the `d` property instead:

```css
.line{
transition: .3s;
transform-origin: left;
}

body:hover .line{  d: path('m15.665 25.123h40v1h-40z')}
```

```html
<div>

<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 62 52" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <path class="line" d="m15.665 25.123h20v1h-20z" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Thanks to [CSS change d property of <path>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227012/css-change-d-property-of-path)